# Get XPath of element where parent contains specific text

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have code which looks like below and I want to click on 'View Details' but where tag p contains text as 'Dublin'
How can I get xpath?

```html
<div class="office-name">
    <p class="">Dublin</p>
    <p class="abc">
        <a target="abc" >View map</a>
        <a href="">View details</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
//p[contains(text(), 'Dublin')]
 /following-sibling::p[@class="abc"][1]
     /a[contains(text(),'View details')]
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, this  may work but the framework which I am using doesnt support using following-sibling::
is there any other way ?

Comment: You could try `//div[@class="office-name"][p[contains(text(), 'Dublin')]]/p[@class="abc"][1]/a[contains(text(),'View details')]`

Comment: How to do described action if "Dublin" is variable (say I add this element during runtime and each time it has different text)?  It is not possible to use  "p[contains(text(), '" + dublin_var + "')]..." as I use Page Factory

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming this is how the html looks:

```
<div class="office-name">
    <p class="">Dublin
        <a target="abc" >View map</a>
        <a href="">View details</a>
    </p>
    <p class="abc">
        <a target="abc" >View map</a>
        <a href="">View details</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

Given that, one xpath that will work is:

```
//p[contains(text(), 'Dublin')]/a[contains(text(),'View details')]
```

Okay, sorry, I misunderstood your HTML.  This selector will work, but I don't know if `following` is supported:

```
//div[@class='office-name']/p[contains(text(), 'Dublin')]/following::p/a[contains(text(),'View details')]
```

Comment: Nope, HTML looks the way I pasted so I can reach to View details with below xpath

//div[@class=''office-name]/p/a[contains(text(),'View details')]

But what I want is it should also check if div[@class=''office-name]/p[has Dublin text]